# Project works when run from processing, but not when I export to an .exe file

Tags: processing, exe

I'm working on a project with two windows, one displays on a TV and the other on a tablet (not duplicate screens). It's an interactive game for kids. When I run within processing it works flawlessly, takes a while to load tho. But when I make an exe file (tried w/ and w/o fullscreen and 64/32 bit) it still starts the loading screen but then stays stuck on the loading screen forever. Anyone have any suggestions as to what might be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Sorry but your question too broad for Stack Overflow. What language are you using?  How are you compiling it (assuming you are compiling it)?  There are so many possible causes it makes your question impossible to answer.  Maybe the TV you are using have specific requirements that the application does not meet. The code in your application might be causing memory problems causing a crash ect Without *specific* details it is hard to give an exact answer.  You have also used tags that not many people visit so I advise retagging

Comment: I suggest you try and reproduce the error and find out what exactly what is causing the problem. Remove parts of your application until it works, then you know what is wrong and look for an answer for that.  I realise that this is of little help, but as I said above it's a very hard question to answer without knowing the details (and you probably don't want to spill out the guts of your program anyway). Sorry I can't be of more help.  Good luck and I hope you get your problem solved soon.

Comment: Try running the program via the command line to see any errors you're encountering.